# How to pass antiforgery token and serialized object as parameter to MVC action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to pass both an AntiForgery token and a stringified serialized object to an action, but after all sorts of attempts, I still cannot.

I have tried to send them as comma delimited parameters as well as including the token in the stringified parameter.

```
var jsonModelData = JSON.stringify(
{       
    'personViewModel': serializedObject['PersonViewModel'],
    'identityUserViewModel': serializedObject['IdentityUserViewModel'],
    'entityPersonAddressViewModel' :  entityAddressSerializedObject['EntityPersonAddresses'],
    'telephoneViewModel': telephoneSerializedObject,
    'virtualAddressViewModel': virtualAddressSerializedObject
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "@Url.Action("Save")",
    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token }, jsonModelData,
    success: function (data)
    {
```

which works against the validator, but the stringified parameter of serialized objects is then null
and then also this (which does not get past the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] )

```
var jsonModelData = JSON.stringify(
{
    '__RequestVerificationToken': token,
    'personViewModel': serializedObject['PersonViewModel'],
    'identityUserViewModel': serializedObject['IdentityUserViewModel'],
    'entityPersonAddressViewModel':      entityAddressSerializedObject['EntityPersonAddresses'],
    'telephoneViewModel': telephoneSerializedObject,
    'virtualAddressViewModel': virtualAddressSerializedObject
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "@Url.Action("Save")",
    data:  jsonModelData,
```

and the Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(PersonViewModel personViewModel
                                 , IdentityUserViewModel identityUserViewModel
                                 , List<EntityPersonAddress> entityPersonAddressViewModel
                                 , List<TelephoneViewModel2> telephoneViewModel
                                 , List<VirtualAddressViewModel> virtualAddressViewModel)
{
}
```

**Edit and solution:**

I had to change my action's parameter to a named parameter with the various objects bundled under one class and include the Token as the first parameter in the ajax and also omit the ajax contentType  of "application/json;etc".

It looks like this now.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "@Url.Action("Save")",
    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, MultiViewModel: jsonModelData},
```

and the Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Save(PersonUserModel MultiViewModel) {
```

where the 'PersonViewModel' is a class which contains all the previous and individually stated viewModels.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a header to your $.ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",    
headers: { "csrf-token": token }
```

fill the token variable with something like this

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf


  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.token = "@Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken";
  </script>
```

Comment: It's not getting past the validator attribute on the action.

Comment: you sure var token is set? check it by console.logging it

Comment: Logging it gives me    token=BIwqnYjC-G0nv3VSoJDcQNlxOAmVYRqOwmaGmcNEgnUGeugMpS3tfvzSY5O8vRRwOfoE19sW_W1nAis1Mpuumhu93CLziiHRWFJJtUSmcEc1
  which I assume is correct.
If I put that in as the first parameter in the data it goes thru, but my objects are then all with empty values. So, The value must be correct

Comment: maybe it's because of the parameters in your action. when you remove the attribute [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  do you hit the action? Put a debugger on the action

Comment: Yep, it does hit the action then

Comment: oke, i editted the anwer with an example how to fill the variable from the server. maybe the token is expired.

Comment: I'm using razor to insert it as per;
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id =    "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
    {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   }

Comment: Nope: it sees that as invalid syntax (The @Xsrf. is underlined in red.)

Comment: did you inject @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf on top of your razor view?

Comment: The '@inject ..' is also underlined in red

Comment: var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();  
works too

Comment: I'm not using .net core, just MVC 5 and VS 2017 and latest jquery libraries.

Comment: var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();  doesn't work?

Comment: the var token as suggested does work. Well it logs a value to the console

Comment: It doesn't hit the action. I tried now as well without parameters on the ajax and on the action,  with the header in the ajax call and with the validator uncommented

Answer (score 0):

Answered as per Edit in the question: